# JSON format via AJAX

Tags: javascript

i getting the json response via ajax so when i doing alert of the json response array length is showing correctly the code is

```
try {
    xmlHttp.open("GET", "ajaxmodel_new.php?model_id="+model_id,true);
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status==200){
        model_details_json =  JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText)
        alert(model_details_json.communication.length)
        }
    }
```

so the alert is giving as 4 .... the same thing i.e so i need to use model_details_json.communication.length in other function say

```
function options(){

    document.getElementById('selected_opt').style.display = '';

    if(model_details_json.communication.length != 0 ){
}
}
```

it is showing error as model_details_json.communication is undefined , here model_details_json is an global varaible

Comment: call the function `options()` within the callback function of ajax.

Answer (score 1):

If options() is being called before the AJAX Objects receives the response it is NULL and therefore you can't access.communication.length.

Answer (score 1):

Are you making sure that you're only calling options when the response is ready? Since `model_details_json` is only defined in your if block after the response is ready, it will be undefined otherwise.

In the try block you're checking to make sure that the response is ready before checking the length of `model_details_json`.

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring model_details_json somewhere outside of your functions so it's scope is global:

```
var model_details_json;

function options() {
...
}
```

That will make the variable available to both of your functions.